# Efficient way to construct an XML document from a string containing well formed XML for navigation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a string that contains well formed xml in it. I want to navigate the XML in that string to extract the text in certain nodes. How do I efficiently accomplish this using a built-in .NET class. Which .NET XML class would you use and why?

Many thanks for your help.

Note 1: Linq is not available to me.
Note 2: Editing the XML is not important. Read-only access is what I need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For speed, use an `XmlReader`:

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(myString))
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "foo")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xr.ReadString());
        }
    }
}
```

The above prints out the text content of every element named "foo" in the XML document.  (Well, sort of.  `ReadString` doesn't handle nested elements very gracefully.)

Using an `XPathDocument` is slower, because the entire document gets parsed before you can start searching it, but it has the merit of simplicity:

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(myString))
{
    XPathDocument d = new XPathDocument(sr);
    foreach (XPathNavigator n in d.CreateNavigator().Select("//foo/text()"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
    }
}
```

If you're not concerned with performance or memory utilization, it's simplest to use an `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml(myString);
foreach (XmlNode n in d.SelectNodes("//foo/text()"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer with code samples. As a side note, `XPathNodeIterator` implements `IEnumerable`, so there's no need to use `while` - `foreach` will do the trick as well, and is easier to read.

Answer (score 11):

For navigation? Probably [`XPathDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx):

```
string s = @"<xml/>";
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(s));
```

From MSDN,

> Provides a fast, read-only, in-memory representation of an XML document by using the XPath data model.

Unlike `XmlDocument` etc, it is optimised for readonly usage; more efficient but less powerful (i.e. you can't edit it). For notes on how to query it, [see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333).

Comment: It should be noted that `XPathDocument` is actually _significantly_ faster on some kinds of XPath queries; notably anything involving `preceding` or `preceding-sibling` axis.

Comment: Be aware that you haven't called Dispose() on the StringReader you created in this example.  See Robert Rossney's accepted answer.

Comment: @ALEXintlsos don't get me wrong: normally I'm exceptionally pedantic about `IDisposable`; but: `StringReader` is just one of those cases where it *really, really* isn't going to matter. Is it more correct to dispose it? sure. Will it *ever* matter, in *any* way? Nope ;p

Comment: Ugh; how do we know that?  I sure do wish there were a way to know when framework classes pointlessly inherit from IDisposable, or that the compiler or code analysis tools would tell people that their class holds neither native resources nor IDisposable objects, so they don't pointlessly inherit from IDisposable.  My favorite case: [WCF clients](http://digitalimperativelog.alexoss.net/2011/08/wcf-client-disposal-broken.html).  ...I miss my C++ destructors.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [XmlDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(VS.71).aspx) to get a DOM from the string.  Then you can traverse it using the appropriate DOM methods or XPATH as needed.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the structure of XML. If it is relatively simple, then the most efficient way to wrap the string into `StringReader`, and then wrap that into `XmlReader`. The benefit is that you won't have to create an XML tree in memory, copying data from the string - you'll just read nodes one by one.

If the document structure is complicated enough, you might need (or want) a DOM - in which case `XDocument.Parse` should do the trick.

Comment: I dont see the point in wrapping it inside a StringReader. As far as I know, the only purpose of StringReader is to have mutable strings such that when a lot of string operations are performed. The overhead of creating new strings for every string manipulation is gone with StringReader. I dont see how that fits here?

Comment: @Henry: You're confusing `StringWriter` with `StringReader`. `StringReader` is used here to provide `TextReader` interface on top of a plain string, because `XmlReader.Create` expects `TextReader`.

Comment: @Newbite: if you don't have LINQ, then pick either `XmlDocument` or `XPathDocument` depending on your requirements. If you're only going to read data, `XPathDocument` would likely be better.